# Converting Block of code Into Function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, php-5.3

I have those few lines of code:

```
        $array_to_filter // this array is unfiltered

   array_filter($array_to_filter, function($v){return array_filter($v) == array();});
    $c = function($v){
    return array_filter($v) != array();
    };
    $filtered_array = array_filter($airbnb, $c);


    print_r($filtered_array); // this is filtered array!
```

Now I will be using this piece of code alot in my code and I don't want to repeat it every time! I have tried to do this:

```
    function filter_array ($tofilter, $filtered) {

    array_filter($tofilter, function($v){return array_filter($v) == array();});
    $c = function($v){
    return array_filter($v) != array();
    };
    $filtered = array_filter($filtered, $c); 
    return $filtered;
}
```

And calling it like this: filter_array($array_to_filter, $filtered_array);

Without any luck.. What am I doing wrong?

The array I want to filter:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [RES_ID] => 2927135
        [CONFIRMATION] =>  QBMNMA
        [AIRBNB_AGENCY_INCOME] =>  €497
        [AIRBNB_INCOME] =>  €516

        [AIRBNB_FEES] =>  -€19

        [AIRBNB_PER_NIGHT] =>  €129
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [RES_ID] => 
        [CONFIRMATION] => 
        [AIRBNB_AGENCY_INCOME] => 
        [AIRBNB_INCOME] => 
        [AIRBNB_FEES] => 
        [AIRBNB_PER_NIGHT] => 
    )
```

The result via the block of code:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [RES_ID] => 2927135
        [CONFIRMATION] =>  QBMNMA
        [AIRBNB_AGENCY_INCOME] =>  €497
        [AIRBNB_INCOME] =>  €516

        [AIRBNB_FEES] =>  -€19

        [AIRBNB_PER_NIGHT] =>  €129
    )
```

The result via the function:

```
<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Welcome.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 456</p>
```

Comment: Define "without any luck".  How does it fail?

Comment: I get back null arrays. Unfiltered. like this function was never used.

Comment: Well, *was* it used?  Where/how do you use it?  When you debug it, where exactly do any of the runtime values become something unexpected?

Comment: Which line is line 456? I'm betting it's $c = function($v){

Comment: FYI, your first call to `array_filter` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: What is the function suppose to do. Explain in words.

Comment: I have an Associative array but some of the arrays are empty! inside for example the [RES_ID] =>  I want to get rid of this whole array not just the key. that's what it does

Comment: It is the Associative array you can see under the "The array I want to filter:"

Comment: i thought the array you wanted to filter was `$array_to_filter` ... This is too confusing.

Comment: This is just example so you can understand what is going on

Comment: Well, your variable naming is inconsistent and confusing. It is the opposite of helping.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the $airbnb to the $array_to_filter. I've included a comment // this array is unfiltered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an Associative array but some of the arrays are empty! inside for example the [RES_ID] => I want to get rid of this whole array not just the key. that's what it does –  Valery 5 mins ago

```
function filter_array ($to_filter)
{
    foreach ($to_filter as $index => $child_array)
    {
        if (!array_filter($child_array)) {
            // all keys are empty.
            unset($to_filter[$index]);
        }
    }

return $to_filter;
}

$filtered_array = filter_array($array_to_filter);
```

Would this work?